# Creating a variable counter in javascript with variable speed

Tags: javascript

I'm having a problem.
I want to make a counter that counts from 1 to 9 and repeats.
The time between the counts should be variable (1 to 10 seconds in the same series).
Sometimes, it should add 1, sometimes 2 (so sometimes skip one number).

Is that possible with javascript?

Thank you in advance.

This is the code I have, but is only counts, does not skip a number sometimes and the time to count is fixed at 500 ms.

`````
  <div id="value">1</div>
  <script>
function animateValue(id){
    var obj = document.getElementById(id);
    var current = obj.innerHTML;
    setInterval(function(){
    obj.innerHTML = current++;
    },500);
}
animateValue('value');
</script>
   </html>````
`````

Comment: Yes, all of this is possible. Use `setTimeout` and generate the different counts based on your requirements. Not sure what logic is used to determine when to skip/add 1 vs 2, but instead of `current++`, you could do `obj.innerHTML = current + count`, with count being 1 or 2 or whatever number.

Comment: How do i change the 500 ms with a setTimeout? Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Kargui, I've added an answer that explains the use of setTimeout. In order to change the 500ms, you'll need to recursively call the function that invokes `setTimeout`. The function that calls setTimeout will be responsible for generating your timer value.

Answer (score 1):

First, a JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/5k0xsrj6/embedded/result/

JSFiddle with larger, stylized text:
https://jsfiddle.net/9f4vgLbx/embedded/result

### Edit: I see you're not familiar with JavaScript. I've included non-ES6 JavaScript as well.

The biggest issue you'll face with your code is the use of `setInterval`, as you want a variable timer.

Instead of `setInterval`, consider a function that calls itself and sets a timer. Once the `setTimeout` is called, it will invoke the function again to set another timeout, effectively creating an interval.

#### Non ES6 Script:

```
var el = document.body;
var max_count = 9;
var current_count = 1;

// Function which sets our timer
function timer(delay) {
    // Set a timeout with our passed `delay` arg
    setTimeout(function () {
        // Adds either 1 or 2 based on the return value of getIteration
        current_count += getIteration();

        // As we have a max, reset to 1 if we're over
        if (current_count > max_count) {
            current_count = 1;
        }

        // Update innerHTML
        writer();

        // Call next iteration
        loop();

    }, delay);
}

// Writes our innerHTML
function writer() {
    el.innerHTML = current_count;
}

// Returns 1000 through 10000
function getDelay() {
    return Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10) * 1000;
}

// Returns either 1 or 2
function getIteration() {
    return Math.ceil(Math.random() * 2);
}

// Our main function to loop
function loop() {
    // getDelay will return a value between 1000 - 10000
    timer(getDelay());
}

// Sets Initial Value
writer();

// Main
loop();
```

#### Original:

Here's an example of the code on the JSFiddle. I've included comments to hopefully explain the logic.

```
{
    const el = document.body;
    const max_count = 9;
    let current_count = 1;

    // Function which sets our timer
    const timer = delay => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            current_count += getIteration();

            if (current_count > max_count) {
                current_count = 1;
            }

            // Update innerHTML
            writer();

            // Call next iteration
            main();

        }, delay);
    }

    // Writes our innerHTML
    const writer = (str, log) => {
        if (log) {
            console.log(str);
        } else {
            el.innerHTML = `Current count: ${current_count}`;
        }
    }

    // Returns 1000 through 10000
    const getDelay = () => {
        return Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10) * 1000;
    }

    // Returns either 1 or 2
    const getIteration = () => {
        return Math.ceil(Math.random() * 2);
    }

    // Our main function to loop
    const main = () => {
        const delay = getDelay();

        writer(`Next delay is ${delay}ms`, true);

        timer(delay);
    }

    // Set Initial Value
    writer();

    // Main
    main();
}
```

Hope this helps! If you have any questions, feel free to ask!

Comment: Nice, thank you very much, that what was it needed to be. I appreciate that! One last question: can I change the font size of the output? Thanks

Comment: @Kargui - Absolutely. I'm using `document.body` directly to inject our content, but you can easily query another element and use CSS to style the output. Here's a JSFiddle with an example of that: https://jsfiddle.net/9f4vgLbx/ (or the embedded version: https://jsfiddle.net/9f4vgLbx/embedded/result)

Comment: I'm glad this worked. I'm upvoting it and deleting my answer, which is now redundant at best.